# History Function similar VBA Code assigned to every incident

Tags: ms-access, vba

having some trouble with my history function. Since the inbuilt ColumnHistory Code was to inflexible I just wrote a short VBA code to do it better.

I have two separate problems:

1. Code writes in History Window of every issue

I have a form where I can add new incidents and flip through the incidents. Like the template issue.db.
But my code writes the updates to all incidents in my form. So when I make a comment "abc" to Issue 1 in the History appears "Version date abc" but this also appears at issue 2 and so on.
How can I prevent that this happens?

1. vbCrLf isn't working

I don't know why but vbCrLf isn't working.. I doesn't make a line break. Just is ignored at the code. Rich format is activated.

```
Private Sub txt_Comments_W9_LostFocus()

Dim temp As String, newComment As String, Version As String

temp = ""
newComment = ""

temp = txt_History_W9.Value

Version = "----------------------" & "Version " & Date & ": " & "----------------------"
newComment = Version & txt_Comments_W9.Value
txt_History_W9.Value = temp & vbCrLf & vbCrLf & newComment
```

End Sub

Thank you guys

Comment: 1) Sounds like you got a form in continuous view and an unbound textbox you are writing to. Bind the textbox to a field of your table.

Comment: Hey. Thank you that should be the solution for that problem! Do you have a proposal why the line break isn't working?

Comment: Is VB but have a look at http://www.vbforums.com/showthread.php?251402-vbcrlf-not-working-in-text-box

Comment: Ah thanks. So simply not working :) Thank you Roland!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For 2) I have found this workaround: http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/e45dd35c-1848-4140-93a8-08fc00a67b5f/access-rich-text-box